# How to invite facebook friends from iPhone application?

Tags: ios, facebook

In my application I displayed Facebook friends list and I want to invite Facebook friends by using fbconnect API. Please refer me to any example code or tutorial.

Comment: This isn't an answer but one thing I've learned when using the FB iOS SDK is that it's often wrong or does things that aren't explained in the docs. YMMV but the SDK seems like a piece of crap.

Answer (score 2):

Can't currently do this, has been in their bug tracker for awhile:
[facebook bug tracker](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9254)

UPDATE: Link now says that this has been fixed, feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a tool called [foorocket](http://www.foorocket.com/). It gives you Facebook connect, inviting friends & SMS sharing with one line of code. In private beta.. works great!